# C#: создание экземпляра Класса в дочерней форме и передача его на главную

Tags: c#, winforms, ооп

**Добрый день!**
Вопрос с следующем:

как передать экземпляр класса с дочерней формы (OpenDialog) (оно тут был создан и заполнен) на главную, из которой вызывался диалог?

**Спасибо.**

Comment: Эээ... миллионом разных способов. Дочерняя форма может знать главную и «дёрнуть» за нужный метод. Главная может знать дочернюю и спросить у неё нужную информацию. Объект состояния программы может получить данные от дочерней формы, а главная форма оттуда прочитать. Дочерняя форма может опубликовать event, а главная на него подписаться.

---
Вы неправильный вопрос задаёте. Спросите себя лучше, какой объект что должен знать, и кто кого должен извещать. Ответите на этот вопрос — технические вопросы станут не проблемой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов много. Можно или через событие, или через свойства. Через свойство, Вы просто после закрытия диалога, до уничтожения формы, читаете нужное свойство. Через событие, подписываетесь на него в главной форме, в нужное время вызываете это событие в дочерней форме.